# How to add an Array with elements to a method?

Tags: java, arrays

Sorry guys, I will reiterate the question. I have an array with 12 elements:

`1.6, 2.1, 1.7, 3.9, 3.7, 3.9, 2.9, 4.3, 2.4, 3.7`

I want to get the largest value in this array. Question is how can I invoke the method from my main class to an object created in my driver class?

```
//MAIN CLASS
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Rainfall
{
    private double total = 0;
    private double average;
    private double max;
    private double smallest;
    private double rain[];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public Rainfall(double...rainfall)
{
 double[] rain = {1.6 , 2.1, 1.7, 3.9, 3.7, 3.9, 2.9, 4.3, 2.4, 3.7};
}


public double getTotal()
{
    total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
        total = total + rain[i];
}
    System.out.println("The total rainfall for the year is: " + total);

    return total;
}

public double getAverage()
{
    average = total/12;

    System.out.println("The average monthly rainfall is: " + average);

    return average;
}

public double getMostRain()
{

    double max = 0;
    int maxind = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if (rain[i] > max)
        {
            max = rain[i];
            maxind = i;
        }
    }

System.out.println("The largest amout of rainfall was: " + max +
        "inches in month" + (maxind + 1));

return max;
}

public double getLeastRain()
{
    double smallest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    int smallind = 0;

for(int n = 0; n < 12; n++)
{
    if (rain[n] < smallest)
    {
        smallest = rain[n];
        smallind = n;
    }
}


System.out.println("The smallest amout of rainfall was" + smallest +
        "inches in month " + (smallind + 1));

return smallest;
}
}



//DriverClass

public class RainfallDriver {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] list = {1.6 , 2.1, 1.7, 3.9, 3.7, 3.9, 2.9, 4.3, 2.4, 3.7};

    //Counts the total and average from the elements in the array
    double total = 0;
    double average =0;
    for (double element : list)
        total += element;
            average = total/12;






    System.out.println("Total: " + total);
    System.out.println("Smallest: " +rain.getLeastRain());     //How can I call the method?
    System.out.println("Largest: " + rain.getMostRain());      //How can I call the method?
    System.out.println("Average: " + average);
}

}
```

Comment: That is not a class, it's two methods. There is also no ``main``. Please update your question with all of the relevant information. Tagging your question with a language would also be helpful, is this Java?

Comment: @aruisdante I have a bunch of methods that I want to invoke in my Driver class. Where and how exactly can I create an array with the 12 elements so that I am able to call the methods from the main class.. I'm sorry that my code is so messy.. I have been on this for quite some time now..It's driving me nuts!

Comment: @misheekoh: Re: "I'm sorry that my code is so messy": You don't need to apologize. Just clean it up, and no one will care that it used to be messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, you don't quite understand what OOP is, and how to use it:

You are writing a class called `Rainfall`, and you are (correctly) declaring its members (attributes)... but you are not initializing them! Your constructor declares a **local** variable with the same name as one of your class's attributes, but doesn't use it anywhere.

If what I am seeing is right, then what you want is something like this:

```
public class Rainfall {
    private double[] rain;
    /*
      It is a good idea to make the attributes private, and then access them
      through methods (getters to get the values, setters to change the values)
    */
    // more attributes  here
    public Rainfall(double[] rain) {
        this.rain = rain; // THIS IS THE WAY how you initialize an attribute
    }
    public double getRain() {
        /*
           Remember what I said about getters? This is an example
         */
        return rain;
    }
    public void setRain(double[] rain) {
        /*
           Remember what I said about setters? This is an example
         */
        this.rain = rain;
    }
    // More code...
}
```

And now, if you want to use this array in another class, you can write something like this:

```
public class SomeOtherClass {
    // Some code
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rainfall rainfall = new Rainfall(); // Declare and instantiate the object
        double[] rain = rainfall.getRain(); // Retrieve the value of the attribute
        /*
          And now... how to get the max value? Here's an example
         */ 
        double maxVal = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        for(double x : rain) {
            if(x > maxVal)
                maxVal = x;
        }
        // More code
    }
}
```

---

I really recommend you take a good read to [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Java 8, the new [Lambda Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) solve the problem in a nice one-liner:

```
double max = Arrays.stream(rain).max().getAsDouble();
```

The reason why you need to call the trailing `getAsDouble()` method is because the `max()` method returns an [OptionalDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalDouble.html), because Java needs a way of handling the possibility that the `rain` array may be empty.

Likewise, your other methods can be implemented like:

```
double min = Arrays.stream(rain).min().getAsDouble();
double average = Arrays.stream(rain).average().getAsDouble();
```

or together:

```
DoubleStream rainStream = Arrays.stream(rain);
double max = rainStream.max().getAsDouble();
double min = rainStream.min().getAsDouble();
double average = rainSteam.average().getAsDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking... But something like this would work to find the largest element of the `rain` array.

```
int largestNum = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < 12; i++ ) 
{
     if ( rain [ i ] >= largestNum )
        {
            largestNum = rain[ i ];
        }            
}
```